# Create an array, hashtable and dictionary?

Tags: powershell

What is the proper way to create an array, hashtable and dictionary?

```
$array = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
```

`$array.GetType()` returns ArrayList, OK.

```
$hashtable = [System.Collections.Hashtable]
```

`$hashtable.GetType()` returns RuntimeType, Not OK.

```
$dictionary = ?
```

How to create a dictionary using this .NET way?

What is the difference between dictionary and hashtable? I am not sure when I should use one of them.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The *proper* way (i.e. the PowerShell way) is:

Array:

```
> $a = @()
> $a.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Hashtable / Dictionary:

```
> $h = @{}
> $h.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

The above should suffice for most dictionary-like scenarios, but if you did explicitly want the type from `Systems.Collections.Generic`, you could initialise like:

```
> $d = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,string]'
> $d.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Dictionary`2                             System.Object

> $d["foo"] = "bar"
> $d | Format-Table -auto

Key   Value
---   -----
foo   bar
```

Comment: Interesting... why does the latter part of the dictionary creation code require ' '? I imagine it has to do with the `[string, string]` part, because creating a list without ' ' works just fine.

Answer (score 42):

If you want to initialize an array you can use the following code:

```
$array = @()    # empty array
$array2 = @('one', 'two', 'three')   # array with 3 values
```

If you want to initialize hashtable use the following code:

```
$hashtable = @{}   # empty hashtable
$hashtable2 = @{One='one'; Two='two';Three='three'}   # hashtable with 3 values
```

Hashtable and dictionary in Powershell is pretty much the same, so I suggest using hashtable in almost all cases (unless you need to do something in .NET where Dictionary is required)

Comment: They're not pretty much the same, they have some significant differences. From a basic usability standpoint they have some overlap.